# Task Scheduler in C# for the specific day

Tags: c#

By using below code snippet, I can schedule my task but the problem is task is getting scheduled for all days from the starting day i.e. DailyTrigger. I wanted it to schedule the task for the specific day not daily and dont wanted it to be ran automatically for next day again. How can I achive this?

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
// this is the 2.0 library 
namespace TaskSchedulerForDataUsage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (TaskService myTaskService = new TaskService())
            {
                TaskDefinition myTaskDefinition = myTaskService.NewTask();
                myTaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does Something";
                myTaskDefinition.Triggers.Add(new MonthlyTrigger(1, MonthsOfTheYear.AllMonths));
                myTaskDefinition.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("Here is a path with a .exe ", null, null));
                myTaskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"AwesomeStuff", myTaskDefinition);
                //in case you want to erase the task
                //myTaskService.RootFolder.DeleteTask("AwesomeStuff"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See if there is anything in `.Triggers` collection before you add to it... Maybe `.Clear()` it just in case.

Comment: It is not clear which nuget package the current code is using. When I test this with https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler the triggers collection is as expected.

Comment: Instead of "MonthlyTrigger" need to use other function to execute the task only once but not sure which function should I use?